# Find the maximum score of each student with subject name

Tags: sql

```
studentid   maths   science art computer sports
1             55     68      59   75     62
2             75     68      79   56     89
3             89     85      74   32     56
4             89     92      86   75     12
5             99     100     45  68      45
```

How to get query result like this

```
studentid   maths   science art computer sports

1                                   75  
2                                           89
3             89     
4                     92        
5                     100
```

and like this

```
studentid   MaxScore

1
2                                         
3            
4                      
5
```

Comment: please specify the rdbms, i.e.: sql server, oracle, postgres?

Answer (score 2):

Case 1

```
SELECT studentid, 
       CASE GREATEST(maths,science,art,computer,sports) 
         WHEN maths THEN math
         ELSE ''
       END AS math,
CASE GREATEST(maths,science,art,computer,sports) 
         WHEN science THEN science
         ELSE ''
       END AS science,
CASE GREATEST(maths,science,art,computer,sports) 
         WHEN art THEN art
         ELSE ''
       END AS art,
CASE GREATEST(maths,science,art,computer,sports) 
         WHEN computer THEN computer
         ELSE ''
       END AS computer,
CASE GREATEST(maths,science,art,computer,sports) 
         WHEN sports THEN sports
         ELSE ''
       END AS sports

FROM table_name
```

Case 2

```
SELECT studentid, GREATEST(maths,science,art,computer,sports) as MaxScore
FROM table_name
```

Read about `GREATEST()` here [oracle doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions060.htm) , [Mysql](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_greatest.asp)